# Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' + Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix

I just installed Postfix and configured it to use MySQL. It wasn't sending any emails out after I did that so I checked /var/log/mail.log and it came back with this:

```
postfix/trivial-rewrite[5283]: fatal: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-domains.cf(0,lock|fold_fix): table lookup problem
postfix/cleanup[5258]: warning: AFCDC30437: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for email@email.com
postfix/master[4761]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/trivial-rewrite pid 5282 exit status 1
postfix/proxymap[4126]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (110)
```

In mysql-domains.cf I'm using:

```
Hosts    127.0.0.1
```

I can connect to MySQL with this:

```
mysql -u postfixuser -p
```

But I can't connect this way:

```
mysql -u postfixuser -h 127.0.0.1 -p maildbname
```

Also when I run netstat -l it comes back with:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN
```

I've tried changing my hosts to:

```
Hosts    localhost
```

But then I just get a socket error:

```
postfix/cleanup[4870]: warning: connect to mysql server localhost: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

I also have this set up in the MySQL config file:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Be aware that localhost != 127.0.0.1 in mysql.  When you use "localhost" in mysql it attempts to use the socket instead of a tcp connection to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

In your postfix mysql connection section, I think you want:

```
hosts = unix:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

rather than 127.0.0.1 for postfix.  Alternatively, add a grant to allow postfix to connect via 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost.

```
grant all on postfix.* to postfix@127.0.0.1 identified by 'asdf';
```

Postfix is connecting via TCP, you probably have the grant defined for the socket connection.  Fixing one or the other should fix it.

Comment: Ok....neither one of those worked either, but I think I found out what my problem was. I apparently botched something up in the reverse DNS. So I fixed that and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a firewall might be messing things up. Try telnetting to localhost on port 3306: `telnet localhost 3306` or `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` and see if that connects.

If it does not, try disabling your firewall: `sudo ufw disable`, then try telnetting again.
If it does connect, we've identified your firewall settings as being the culprit, you will need to allow TCP access on your `lo` interface to/from 127.0.0.1 on port 3306.